# In Visual Studio examples, what is the meaning of the ^?

Tags: .net, string, declaration

I see strings declared with a ^, such as **String^ value1 = L"This is a string.";**
I see this in both Microsoft Edge and Chrome, but I cannot find a meaning for it.

Comment: Noting where you see this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`String^ value1 = L"This is a string.";` is a *programming language construct*.  And you haven't told us which language :(

But I'm guessing you probably mean [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), a Microsoft extension to C++.

The `^` symbol is an [handle declarator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/handle-to-object-operator-hat-cpp-component-extensions?view=vs-2019).  It means that the object referred to can be deleted by .Net's garbage collector.

The `L` attribute denotes a Unicode string.  Specifically, a `wchar_t`, UTF-16 Unicode [string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-string-literals?view=vs-2019).